# Give source of image on SD card to image tag in phonegap

Tags: android, image, cordova, android-sdcard, src

I want to assign source of image to img tag in html. The image is saved in the custom folder of sdcard. Please help me to do that. I have searched a lot about this but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it just by providing the path as

```
<img src="file:///mnt/sdcard/abc/def/ghi/xyz.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would solve your problem:

```
function getPathToCustomFolder(callback)
{               
 var customFolderName = "myFunnyImages"
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,                  
  function(fileSys) {
   fileSys.root.getDirectory(customFolderName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
                    function(dir){
    callback(dir.fullPath);
   })
  }, error
 );
}

// After calling this function, you will get the path of your customFolder   
function alertThePath()
{
 getPathToCustomFolder(
  function(result){
   alert(result);
  });
}

// Changes your scr attribute
function showMyImage()
{
 var image = document.getElementById('funnyImage');
 getPathToCustomFolder(
  function(result){
   image.src = result+"/funny1.jpg";
 });
}
```

For more information check out the phonegap FileAPI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bpichon. But as I have mentioned a single line has solved my problem which is exactly dir.fullpath value.